# No File-system for scheme: HTTP when submitted druid task for creation of data-source to supervisor

Tags: hadoop2, druid

1. Setup : HDFS --- Cluster (1-master ,2 Slaves) Druid --- Cluster (1-(zk,coordinator,overload),1-(historical,middile manager),1-(broker))
   Version using for Druid  : imply-2.3.9,HDFS : 2.7.3
2. common.runtime.properties for druid :For HDFS:

   druid.storage.type=hdfs
   druid.storage.storageDirectory=http://hadoopmachince:9000/druid/segments

When i posted task to http://druidip:port/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor for creating datasource . Task get failed with below exception.

Error Stack Trace :
1)Error injecting constructor, java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
  at io.druid.storage.hdfs.HdfsDataSegmentPusher.(HdfsDataSegmentPusher.java:63)
  while locating io.druid.storage.hdfs.HdfsDataSegmentPusher
  at io.druid.storage.hdfs.HdfsStorageDruidModule.configure(HdfsStorageDruidModule.java:97) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> io.druid.storage.hdfs.HdfsStorageDruidModule)
  while locating io.druid.segment.loading.DataSegmentPusher annotated with @com.google.inject.multibindings.Element(setName=,uniqueId=152, type=MAPBINDER, keyType=java.lang.String)

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_ in the Help Centre.

Comment: We have Druid services who is trying to access hadoop cluster .

Answer (score 0):

Need to change  from http to hdfs

common.runtime.properties for druid :For HDFS:

druid.storage.type=hdfs druid.storage.storageDirectory=hdfs://hadoopmachince:9000/druid/segments